# How is a histogram implemented as a data structure?

Tags: data-structures

I'm reading a [paper](https://nomis80.org/ctmf.pdf) about O(1) median filtering. I'm confused how histograms, denoted H, have the properties described. How can histograms be implemented such that: summing histograms, H(A ∪ B) = H(A) + H(B), is a O(1) operation with respect to the number of accumulated [points]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the paper says:

> "Notice that summing histograms is a O(1) operation with respect to the number of accumulated pixels. It depends only on the size of the histogram, which is itself a function of the bit depth of the image".

For example, for a 8-bit image, there are only 256 possible values for the pixel intensity, so the histogram is of size at most 256, regardless of the width or height of the image.  So, you can sum two such histograms with only 256 operations, regardless of the width or height of the image.